How to call function with address[] memory parameter?
I tried everything to call initWallet inside my test file in foundry, but it keeps telling me that the parameter I use for _owners is not convertible to address[] memory.
function initWallet(address[] memory _owners, uint _required, uint _daylimit) public {}

For instance, I tried to call the function as follows:
address A = address(0x0);
address[] memory aa = [A];
X.initWallet(aa, 1, 0);

But then I get the following error:
Error (9574): Type address[1] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type address[] memory.

It is probably just a silly mistake/misunderstanding, but I have been stuck already for a while now :(

You can solve that by creating a dynamic array of fixed size instead of the static one, like:
address A = address(0x0);
address[] memory aa = new address[](1);
aa[0] = A;
X.initWallet(aa, 1, 0);

If you want to do this for multiple random addresses like address(0x0), address(0x1), address(0x2), etc. Then, you can use a loop in which you can iterate a variable of type uint160 and typecasting the same to address, like:
address[] memory aa = new address[](10);

for (uint160 i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    aa[i] = address(i);
}

X.initWallet(aa, 1, 0);

